# Mongoose update first five documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hello I am trying to update only first five documents from my schema using mongoose. I found a way to update documents by giving condition but cant update only first five.

I got this code

```
mongoose.model('person').update( {active:false} , {multi: true} , function(err,docs) { ... });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to get the first 5 `_id` values matching your condition and then pass those using [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) to your update selection:

```js
mongoose.model('person').find({ "active": { "$ne": false }}).limit(5)
    .exec(function(err,docs) {
    var ids = docs.map(function(doc) { return doc._id } );
    mongoose.model('person').update(
       { "_id": { "$in": ids } },
       { "$set": { "active": false } },
       { "multi": true },
       function(err,numAffected) {

       }
    );
});
```

Also notice the correct arguments to the update statement with a "query" and "update" block. You should also be using update operators such as [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/), otherwise you are overwriting the existing document content with just the contents of the "update"block.

Also see the [`.update()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method from the core documentation.